# How do you find the Taylor series of an indefinite integral?

Tags: integration, power-series, taylor-expansion

I am given the following problem :-

[image: 1]

I know that I have to first find the Taylor series of the polynomial and then integrate each term, however I am having trouble finding the Taylor series before integrating because the derivative of $\frac{(e^t-e)}{(t-1)}\to \frac{e^t(t-1)-1(e^t-e)}{(t-1)^2}$ at $t=1$ does not exist $\frac{0}{0}$. How do I go about finding the Taylor series of $\frac{(e^t-e)}{(t-1)}?$

Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: The integrand is only undefined at $x=0$, in a removable way, so its antiderivative is defined everywhere and turns out to be differentiable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

Set $t=1+u\enspace(u\to 0)\,$ first. The integrand becomes
$$\frac{\mathrm e^t-\mathrm e}{t-1}=\mathrm e\,\frac{\mathrm e^u-1}u.$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Sorry, I'm still a little bit confused. If I take the derivative of this function for the first term in the taylor series, wouldn't u^2 be the denominator (leading to a problem when you plug in 0)?

Comment: Why do you want to take the derivative? The numerator has a well-known expansion, and everything simplifies. If you compute the derivative and consider the expansion of the numerator , the terms with order less than $2$ disappear, so it's not indeterminate.

Comment: Oh! I guess I am a bit confused about rules of dividing and adding taylor series... what gives us the ability to just find the taylor series of e^u and then subtract 1 from it and divide it by u ?(I was under the impression that we would have to find the taylor series  for each term and then do operations on them (subtract/add/divide))

Comment: Never mind, I get it now! Thanks for all the walking through!